# How to get custom files of posts on WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

This method `get_posts()` return all fields!

But i need to get custom fields, for example i wanna get only `id` and `title` and their categories name.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the help pages, especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". Also please take the tour and read about how to ask good questions. Lastly please learn how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.

Answer (score 0):

I think by passing parameter you could get what you want.

```
    $args = array( 
      'numberposts'     => -1, // -1 is for all
      'post_type'       => 'movie', // or 'post', 'page'
      'orderby'         => 'title', // or 'date', 'rand'
      'order'       => 'ASC', // or 'DESC'
    );

    // Get the posts
    $posts = get_posts($args);

    // If there are posts
    if($posts){
      // Loop the posts
      foreach ($posts as $post){
        var_dump($mypost->ID); // you have ID here
      }
    }
```

Comment: can u read my question again? i need get array with custom fields! `SELECT ID, TITLE...` with category of this post without content and other fields